# apache, tomcat context path

Tags: apache-httpd, tomcat

I have Tomcat and Apache installed in CentOS 5.
They're integrated with a help of mod_jk.so.

They both display the same in http://www.tource.com/cms/admin and http://www.tource.com:8080/cms/admin

But I'd like to make the context **cms** displayed only when I access with address below.
**http://cms.tource.com/**

How could the context "www.tource.com/cms" turn into "cms.tource.com" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an apache config for this site?  If so, please post it so we can get a better idea of how you have your site set up.

Here is one way to do it (with mod_proxy and mod_rewrite):

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/cms.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName cms.tource.com
        RewriteEngine On
        ProxyPass / http://tource.com:8080/cms/admin
        ProxyPassReverse / http://tource.com:8080/cms/admin
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxy setting in Tomcat **$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" proxyPort="80" />
```

Restart apache and visit cms.tource.com to see if its working for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the web server config of www.tource.com add the following line:

```
Redirect /cms http://cms.tource.com
```

For more information , refer to apache documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html